# Parser exception for /AndroidManifest.xml: Attribute name "**" associated with an element type "service" must be followed by the ' = ' character

Tags: android, xml, permissions

Im getting an error in my manifest file.

Parser exception for /Cheve En Breve App/AndroidManifest.xml: Attribute name "andrcom.chevenbreve.app.libraries.ServiceNotification" associated with an element type "service" must be followed by the ' = ' character.

Can't seem to get it fixed, any suggestions?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.chevenbreve.app"
    android:versionCode="7"
    android:versionName="2.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

        <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

        <!-- Permission to vibrate -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- External storage for caching. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <!-- My Location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <!-- change com.pongodev.perkututapp with your own package name -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <!-- End of copy. -->

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/logo"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Apptheme" >

        <!-- Admob  -->
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <!-- You must insert your own Google Maps for Android API v2 key in here.  -->
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyC29XS3jhhrZGOh3wdSN5iDZeRELhavI4E"/>   

        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>


        <activity
            android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.ActivitySplash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Apptheme.NoActionBar"
            android:noHistory="true" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.ActivityHome"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
               android:value="com.chevenbreve.app.ActivitySearch" />

        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.ActivitySearch"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data 
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.ActivityPlaceAroundYou"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/page_around_you" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.ActivityCategory"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/page_category" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.ActivityPlaceList"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/page_place_list" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.ActivityDetailPlace"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/page_detail_place" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.ActivitySetting"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/page_setting" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.ActivityShare"
            android:label="@string/page_share" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.ActivityAbout"
            android:label="@string/page_about" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.ActivityDirection"
            android:label="@string/direction" />

        <activity 
            android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.ActivityBrowser"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
                   android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
             android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <provider android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.libraries.SuggestionProvider" com.chevenbreve.app.libraries.SuggestionProviderrities="com.chevenbreve.app.libraries.SuggestionProvider"/>

         <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
         <service android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.libraries.ServiceNotification" andrcom.chevenbreve.app.libraries.ServiceNotification
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.chevenbreve.app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.GCMIntentService"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: you've got double type in `<service android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.libraries.ServiceNotification" andrcom.chevenbreve.app.libraries.ServiceNotification`

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest.xml contains some obvious mistakes, I have corrected it for you, use the following code instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.chevenbreve.app"
    android:versionCode="7"
    android:versionName="2.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

        <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

        <!-- Permission to vibrate -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- External storage for caching. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <!-- My Location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <!-- change com.pongodev.perkututapp with your own package name -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <!-- End of copy. -->

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/logo"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Apptheme" >

        <!-- Admob  -->
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <!-- You must insert your own Google Maps for Android API v2 key in here.  -->
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyC29XS3jhhrZGOh3wdSN5iDZeRELhavI4E"/>   

        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>


        <activity
            android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.ActivitySplash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Apptheme.NoActionBar"
            android:noHistory="true" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.ActivityHome"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
               android:value="com.chevenbreve.app.ActivitySearch" />

        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.ActivitySearch"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data 
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.ActivityPlaceAroundYou"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/page_around_you" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.ActivityCategory"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/page_category" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.ActivityPlaceList"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/page_place_list" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.ActivityDetailPlace"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/page_detail_place" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.ActivitySetting"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/page_setting" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.ActivityShare"
            android:label="@string/page_share" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.ActivityAbout"
            android:label="@string/page_about" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.ActivityDirection"
            android:label="@string/direction" />

        <activity 
            android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.ActivityBrowser"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
                   android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
             android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <provider android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.libraries.SuggestionProvider" android:authorities="com.chevenbreve.app.libraries.SuggestionProvider"/>

         <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
         <service android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.libraries.ServiceNotification" 
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.chevenbreve.app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name="com.chevenbreve.app.GCMIntentService"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Changed code as suggested but now I get this error:

com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /Users/TheGraphicAsylum/Documents/workspace/Perkutut V 1.2.1/Projects/Perkutut V.1.2.1/AndroidManifest.xml: Attribute "name" bound to namespace "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" was already specified for element "service".

Comment: @GraphicAsylum It's because your Service contains two "name" attribute. The code has been corrected.